# Task to get executed after compile

Tags: dependencies, sbt, task

I need a task *myTask* to get executed after compile task is finished.
I have tried a number of things I've found on this forum:

- using **dependsOn** --> only working if "sbt myTask" is explicitly called on sbt prompt. But I need myTask to be executed automatically, whenever compile is executed.
- using **triggeredBy** --> myTask gets never called

Doing the other way around works like a charm, although it is not what I want.
I mean, doing:

*(compile in Compile) <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn myTask*

makes myTask to get executed in the first place, and then the compile task is executed.
But I need myTask to get executed after compile is over.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `triggeredBy(compile in Compile)` should do what you want. Can you provide a example build.sbt where it isn't working?

Comment: can you provide a simplified version of your `build.sbt`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to modify the compile task to invoke `anotherTask`. Add the following in your `build.sbt`.

```
lazy val anotherTask = taskKey[Unit]("another task")

anotherTask := println("hello")

compile in Compile := {
    val compileAnalysis = (compile in Compile).value
    anotherTask.value
    compileAnalysis
}
```

Comment: Marios, Lykathia. Thanks a lot for the follow-up on this issue. Here is what I'm doing:  lazy val compileScalastyle = TaskKey[Unit]("compileScalastyle")        compileScalastyle := ScalastylePlugin.scalastyle.in(Compile).toTask("")      compile in Compile := {
  val compileAnalysis = (compile in Compile).value
  compileScalastyle.value
  compileAnalysis
}    As per Mario's suggestion. But it still does not work. The compileScalastyle task gets not called at all.

Comment: I  have also tried with things like:  compileScalastyle := ScalastylePlugin.scalastyle.in(Compile).toTask("").triggeredBy (compile in Compile)
But no success at all.   Thanks!

Comment: Hm, I see. Does the order of operation matters? Do want the `compile` first and then the `compileScalastyle`? I am sure what I have will execute both tasks. But I think that SBT will run them both in parallel (so the order will not be respected).

Comment: Hi Marios. Yes, the order matters. In fact, if I do: (compile in Compile) <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn compileScalastyle  ..... it works, I mean, it first runs the compileScalastyle task, and then, once it is completed, it launches the regular scalac compile phase.  But, unfortunately, this is not what I'm looking for.  I understand what you say about the parallel execution, but, actually, when use the last statement, I can see no parallel execution at all. First, compileScalastyle task, and afterwards, the compile task.

Comment: And when I use the initial approach (the one that tries to execute first the compile task and afterwards the compileScalastyle task), only the compile phase is run. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried my example? It always prints "hello" and compiles for me. This means that both tasks should be executed. I am wondering if there is something that we are missing ...

Comment: Hi Marios. Yes, I have tried your example, this way: `compile in Compile := {
  val compileAnalysis = (compile in Compile).value
  compileScalastyle.value
  compileAnalysis
}`   .... But the compileScalastyle gets not executed at all. Only the compile task itself is executed.

Comment: What is your SBT version? I found this for 0.13.8: `complexTask := Def.sequential(clean, lint).value`

Comment: The sbt version is 0.13.8, indeed. When I do: `enhancedCompile := Def.sequential(compile, compileScalastyle).value`  the sbt complains, saying type error in expression.

Comment: I see, the problem is that the return type is of the last Task and not the first one ... so close.

Comment: Ok, now the sbt is not complaining, but again, the second task gets never called.  The code looks like the following: `lazy val compileScalastyle = TaskKey[Unit]("compileScalastyle")    compileScalastyle := ScalastylePlugin.scalastyle.in(Compile).toTask("")      val enhancedCompile = TaskKey[Unit]("enhancedCompile", "Compile and then check scala style")

val enhancedCompileTask = enhancedCompile := Def.sequential(compile, compileScalastyle).value`
I cannot understand why the second task is not called at all.